# RowDeselect won't fire in custom MvxTableViewSource

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using a custom implementation of MvxTableViewSource but I use it in a multi-select way.

What i try to accomplish is a list that can be selected and deselected (checked/unchecked). The selected command works with the binding. But when I deselect a row in the app, there is no Deselect command i can bind to. Besides that the RowDeselected() method doesn't get fired either.

There seems to be no way to determine what rows have been deselected..

Can somebody point me in the right direction? I really need this!

Tnx

The hook that doesn't get fired:

```
public override void RowDeselected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    //Won't get fired :(
}
```

Also, when i override this method, it first looks like this:

```
public override void RowDeselected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    // NOTE: Don't call the base implementation on a Model class
    // see http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/delegates,_protocols,_and_events
    throw new NotImplementedException ();
}
```

Does this mean it's not implemented in the base as well?

Comment: Fixed it with a simple 'Clean All' The events didn't got mapped by the Xamarin Compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with a simple 'Clean All' The events didn't got mapped by the Xamarin Compiler.